# Django, CRSF Token , POST REQUEST. Works on browser however not on mobile phone

Tags: ajax, django, csrf

As question is being asked in the header.

I'm trying to be more specific here then, pardon my English.

I'm currently working on a jquerymobile website with django on openshift.
I had a login page which uses ajax and sending post request. I've did something like.

```
var account = '{"Email" : "' + username + '" , "Password" : "' + password + '"}';
$.ajax({
url: "/Account/Login",
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", '{{ csrf_token }}');
},
type: "POST",
data: { "account" : account },
success: function(data) {
    var obj = eval("(" + data + ")");
    if (obj.Status == "100")
    {
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
    {
        sessionStorage.user = username;
        window.location = "/";
    }
    }
    else if (obj.Status == "101")
    {
    invalid parameters sent.
    }
    else if (obj.Status == "102")
    {
    email doesnt exist / email & password pair doesn't match.
    }
},  
});
```

Basically the obj.Status is a json reply with Status & Message. username and password are inputs by user. I've also tried by using putting data sent the csrfmiddlewaretoken and it's the same result.

So any solutions? By the way I'm testing it on iPhone 4S and Google Chrome. Thanks in advance people :)

Comment: please don't just ask the question in the title - please put the question into the text body. And please give more details on how it doesn't work. At the very least do `console.log(data)` and add that to your question. And add a `error()` function to the `ajax` paramaters. And please please fix the formatting and indentation of your JS.

Comment: OH AND it's a really really bad idea to use `eval()` in that way. Or in any way. Use JSON instead.

Comment: Thanks people for the comment. Yeah, I'm still a noob programmer, I found out the problem is that in phone browser it doesn't create a CSRF cookie by default when the page loads, is it because of the insecure page problem? Because everytime I view my page with a desktop browser it always prompt to load insecure contents.

Comment: are you sure the csrf token is being set? is CSRF set up properly at the django end? if you view the page with a normal desktop browser is the cookie being set?

Comment: Yup it's properly set. I've actually found out the problem already, it's because I've use something like secure csrf cookie and my page was having unsecured contents like external CSS and js without going through SSL therefore the csrf cookie wasn't auto generated. I've fixed the unsecured pages and removed the secure csrf cookie option so it works properly. Thanks everyone anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `{% csrf_token %}`  inside your template page.

In Javascript:

```
var input = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0]
var csrftoken = input.getAttribute('value');
```

And `csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken` into your POST request data

On the view instead use the `@ensure_csrf_cookie` decorator from `django.views.decorators.csrf`